# Test cases required for Multisig wallet

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet, truffle-contract, parity-wallet

Can you please suggest me some test use cases that are applicable for a smart contract that has a multi-signature wallet in Ethereum?